# css3 animation addition assignment for to{}

Tags: css, animation

I am looking for way to make addition assignment in @keyframe.
for example I want background position change infinity and just go on.

```css
.waterwave{
    background-image: url("../img/waterwave.png");
    height: 215px;
    margin-top: -78px;
    width: 100%;
    animation-name: example;
    animation-duration: 100s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-direction: normal;
}
@keyframes example {
    
    to {background-position: 100px;}
}
```

But I don't want to make absolute value like 100px .
I want something like backgroundPosition: "+=100" in js animation.
Is there any possibility to doing sth like that in css ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a repeating background, the position starts over at the width of the background graphic. For example, if the graphic is 300px wide, then `background-position:50px` looks exactly the same as `background-position:350px`.
So that's what you can use: move the background animation precisely the same width as the graphic, and then it will seamlessly start over. At least if you use the linear function rather than ease-in-out.

```css
.waterwave {
  background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/300/215"); /* a 300px wide image */
  height: 215px;
  margin-top: -78px;
  width: 100%;
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;   /* changed from ease-in-out */
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: normal;
}
@keyframes example {
  to {
    background-position: 300px;        /* this should be the same as the image */
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="waterwave"></div>
```

(in the example I used 5 seconds for the duration, to make the effect visible, but you get the idea.)